# CORS using jQuery 1.8.3 vs 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to make a PATCH/POST using CORS. The code below works on jQuery 1.9.1 but not works on 1.8.3.

```
var settingsB = {
          "async": false,
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": "https://wmmr85ap13.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/customer/" + m,
          "method": "PATCH",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
          },
          "data": JSON.stringify({isFirstLogin: "false"})
        }

        $.ajax(settingsB).done(function (response) {

            console.log(response);
        });
```

On the jquery 1.8.1 I am getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://wmmr85ap13.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/customer/jvthales@gmail.com?{%27isFirstLogin%27:%20false%20}.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://emporiodacerveja.vtexcommercestable.com.br'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   400.

I imagine that the CORS is well configured on the server because the jQuery 1.9.1 works!

Is there any diffence doing post/patch using 1.9.1 vs 1.8.3 version?

EDITED: 
See below the difference between 1.9.1 vs 1.8.3 calls:

[image: jQuery 1.8.3]

[image: jQuery 1.9.1]

Comment: Use the Developer Tools in your browser. Use the Network tab. Compare the request that gets sent for the different versions of jQuery. See what is different about the headers or the body.

Comment: Never ever use `"async": false` . it's a  terrible practice and you should be seeing deprecation warnings

Comment: @Quentin: I attached the Network log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set type and xhrFields

```
$.ajax({
   type : "PATCH",  //replaced my method in 1.9
   url: cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `method` parameter was added in jQuery 1.9.0.

> method 
>   (default: 'GET')  
>   Type: String The HTTP method to use for the
>   request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks! So how can I make a post/get using the jQuery 1.8.1? Is the a way?

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes use `type` which was the standard property for many years